# how can i use this jquery plugin theres no examples or guide

Tags: jquery

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/conmenu

its a plugin for right click menu..... however it has no example usages or illustration or demonstration....

like where can i include additional selector options like top.document, or parent.window.document

```
$.conmenu({
  selector:".node",
  choices:[{
    label:"Edit",
    action:function(div){
      var nid = $(div).attr("id").substring(5);
      window.location.href = "/node/" + nid + "/edit";
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: There's a usage sample right on the page you linked to: "This example shows a 'Edit' option when you right click on any element that has a class of 'node'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking at some other plugins as they are better documented. For example, this plugin has better docs and examples:

http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to use, based on the documentation. Just paste in their sample, and then add in some more menu items, using their code as a template, and see what happens.

If you still have problems then you can ask here, showing the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: I have a problem, the following code (from conmenu source) prevents context menu actions from excecution:

$(document.body).mousedown(function(){ resetMenu(); });

"choices.action" is executed only if I comment this "resetMenu()" out. body.mousedown() is executed before #conmenu.click() and it seems 'click' event never happens.